# How to create unique batch number for the day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want create unique batch number for the day,tomorrow batch number should be max(batchno)+1 . and serial number should be maintain as follows

[record set should be as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oQHQ.jpg)

```
ID    | invoice date   | Batchno     |  seqno
1     | 2019-05-24     |201905000001 | 1
2     | 2019-05-24     |201905000001 | 2
3     | 2019-05-25     |201905000002 | 1
4     | 2019-05-25     |201905000002 | 2

   ON  [dbo].[EBSIEMSTransfernew]
   AFTER INSERT   

AS 

 declare @year varchar(4)
 declare @month varchar(2)
 declare @serialNo varchar(10)

 select @year = year(getdate())
 select @month = REPLICATE('0', 2-len( month(getdate())))+ cast(month(getdate()) as varchar)
 select @serialNo = Max(right(BatchNo,5)) FROM  [Onaccount].[dbo].[EBSIEMSTransfernew] where InvoiceDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) 
 AND InvoiceDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)


BEGIN

UPDATE    [Onaccount].[dbo].[EBSIEMSTransfernew]
SET              BatchNo = @year + @month + REPLICATE('0', 5 - LEN(@serialNo + 1)) + CAST(@serialNo + 1 AS varchar)
FROM         [Onaccount].[dbo].[EBSIEMSTransfernew] INNER JOIN
                      inserted AS i ON EBSIEMSTransfernew.InvoiceDate = i.InvoiceDate
WHERE     (EBSIEMSTransfernew.InvoiceDate = i.InvoiceDate) 

SET NOCOUNT ON;



END


GO
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your code?

Answer (score 1):

For a Daily BATCH number, I would go for the option of using YYYYMMDD as a batch number. Because this is UNIQUE in all sense. So every new day, the date is itself a new UNIQUE batch number as shown below-

```
20190526
20190527
...
20190530
```

As you are managing a daily sequence/serial number starting from 1 everyday, together they will produce a meaningful number as well. You can easily read some value from them. I would suggest to use the 'seqno' something like 0001..0002 based on the guess of Maximum INVOICE may required for a single day.

You can now also generate the Invoice Number from above two number as below-

```
201905260001
201905260002
```

The invoice number will then itself meaningful as it can easily understandable the Invoice belong to date 20190526 and the sell invoice was the first/second sell of that day.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger seems silly.  Why not just use a computed column?

```
alter table EBSIEMSTransfernew
    add batchnumber = datediff(day, '2019-05-04', invoice_date);
```

Admittedly, this will skip days when there are no batches.  If that is an issue, you could generate the value in a view:

```
create view v_EBSIEMSTransfernew as
    select t.*,
           dense_rank() over (order by invoice_date)
    from EBSIEMSTransfernew t;
```

Your description of your issue only mentions a number.  I'm not sure where the rest of the number comes from, but you can modify either of these approaches to add a prefix.

Comment: sir i want to create batch number and sequance number when insert record in to the EBSIEMSTransfernew table by using triiger. it should be as above records set.please help me to this